# Converting portion of TEXT string to datetime causes change of miliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

I have the following type of string I am parsing in SQL server.

```
2014-09-11 10:27:43:616 [This is sample data] attribute=value1; attribute2=142; attribute3=ON;
```

The string is stored in a single TEXT field - as can vary in length by a considerable amount.

I am stripping the datetime portion out, to put into a separate field, however for some reason it *sometimes* comes out different than the original value.

The actual conversion I am using is:

```
CAST(LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST([RAWDATA] AS VARCHAR(MAX)))), 24) AS DATETIME) TEST_DATE
```

For the string above, this gives the datetime value of "2014-09-11 10:27:43.617".

Does anyone know why the miliseconds have increased by 1?

Comment: "SQL Server stores time part as number of 1/300 second long ticks from the midnight." So it's likely your value is rounded to the nearest tick `.616`

Comment: Yes - It does appear this is the same issue, I did look through a search prior to posting, however I evidently didn't phrase as well as I could have!

Comment: You could also use datetime2. It has precision up to as many as 7 decimal places. select CAST('2014-09-11 10:27:43:616' as datetime), CAST('2014-09-11 10:27:43:616' as datetime2(7))